# Apex : SOQL relationship query on master-detail and lookup objects in APEX

Tags: apex, soql, governorlimits

I am trying to create a single query on master-detail and lookup objects

Currently, I have three separate queries, which are able to run in Apex and get the expected results. But, the code approach I have is not the standard.

Output of Query 1 is a list and this list is being iterated. Query2, Query3 are executed in the for loop of Query1 output. And, there are two more for loops to process query2,query3 output and these loops are the for loop Query1 loop.  Below is the code snippet and queries

```
List<ALTIUS__Contracts__c> Details = [soql query1];

if (Details.size() > 0){
List<ContractDataWrapper> contracts= new List<ContractDataWrapper>();

for(ALTIUS__Contracts__c contract : Details){
    ContractDataWrapper wrapper = new ContractDataWrapper();
    wrapper.id = contract.Id;
    wrapper.refnum = contract.ref_num_c;
    wrapper.odnum = contract.od_num_c;
    wrapper.company= contract.ALTIUS__Company__r.Name;
    wrapper.contact= contract.Customer_Contact__r.Name;
    
    List<ALTIUS__Sites__c> sites = [query2];
    
    List<ALTIUS__Products__c > products= [query3];

    if (sites.size() > 0){
       List<Sites> sitesList = new List<Sites>();
       for(ALTIUS__Sites__c site: sites){
           SitesWrapper s = new SitesWrapper();
           s.SiteName =  site.ALTIUS__Site__r.Name;
           s.LocationState = site.ALTIUS__Site__r.ALTIUS__State__c;
           s.LocationCountry = site.ALTIUS__Site__r.ALTIUS__Country__c;
           sitesList.add(s);
        }
        wrapper.Sites = sitesList;
    }

    if (products.size() > 0){
       List<products> productsList = new List<products>();
       for(ALTIUS__Product__r product : products){
           ProductsWrapper p = new ProductsWrapper();
           p.ProductName =  product.ALTIUS__Product__r.ALTIUS__Product_Name__c;
           p.ProductSerialNumber = product.ALTIUS__Product__r.ALTIUS__Serial_Number__c;
           productsList.add(p);
        }
        wrapper.Products = productsList;
    }
}
```

Query 1:

```
SELECT Id, ref_num_c, od_num_c,ALTIUS__Company__r.Name,Customer_Contact__r.Name FROM ALTIUS__Contracts__c 
WHERE ALTIUS__Company__c IN :w.AccountId
```

ALTIUS__Contracts__c Ids from the above query will be used in next two queries which is on lookup objects

Query 2 :

```
SELECT ALTIUS__Site__r.Name, ALTIUS__Site__r.ALTIUS__State__c,ALTIUS__Site__r.ALTIUS__Country__c
FROM ALTIUS__Sites__c WHERE ALTIUS__Contract__c = :contract.Id
```

Query 3 :

```
SELECT ALTIUS__Product__r.ALTIUS__Product_Name__c,ALTIUS__Product__r.ALTIUS__Serial_Number__c 
FROM ALTIUS__Products__c WHERE ALTIUS__Contract__c = :contract.Id
```

I am trying to change this
1.) By converting these three queries to one query and process the result in one for loop without any query execution in the loop

2.)Execute Query1 and get list of Ids

```
Set<Id> contractids = (new Map<Id,ALTIUS__Contract__c>(Details)).keySet();
```

use the contractids in Query2,Query3 with IN operator in the where condition and get the list of sites and products. Create a map with contractid as key and siteslist/productslist in the value and run for loop on query1 results and get the sites and products from Map. But can I create a map with contractid as key for Query2,3 outputs ?

Need advice to take right approach for this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not 3 soqls, but 1 soql + 2 * (amount of records from 1st soql). That's bad practice and you should not perform soql queries in the loop.

You can run 1 query instead:

```
SELECT Id, ref_num_c, od_num_c, ALTIUS__Company__r.Name, Customer_Contact__r.Name,
(SELECT ALTIUS__Site__r.Name, ALTIUS__Site__r.ALTIUS__State__c,ALTIUS__Site__r.ALTIUS__Country__c FROM ALTIUS__Sites__r),
(SELECT ALTIUS__Product__r.ALTIUS__Product_Name__c,ALTIUS__Product__r.ALTIUS__Serial_Number__c FROM ALTIUS__Products__r)
FROM ALTIUS__Contracts__c 
WHERE ALTIUS__Company__c IN :w.AccountId
```

Please, note that the related lists are referred with `__r` notation and do not have WHERE-condition.

After that your for-loop will look like:

```
for (ALTIUS__Contracts__c contract : Details) {
    /*...*/
    for (ALTIUS__Sites__c site : contact.ALTIUS__Sites__r) {/*...*/}
    for (ALTIUS__Products__c product : contact.ALTIUS__Products__r) {/*...*/}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution.

In query2, ALTIUS__Sites__c has a lookup on  ALTIUS__Site__c object and I want to extract fields from  ALTIUS__Site__c. In my general query, I am using `SELECT ALTIUS__Site__r.Name, ALTIUS__Site__r.ALTIUS__State__c` to extract fields from lookup object. How can I change that in the query you have shared ?

Comment: I have removed the ALTIUS__Sites__r subquery and used just ALTIUS__Products__r. It throws error that unable to understand the relationship. ALTIUS__Products__r(Detail) has M-D relationship with ALTIUS__Contracts__c(Master).

Comment: I get unable to understand relationship error for `ALTIUS__Sites__r` and `ALTIUS__Products__r`.
I modified your query like this `SELECT Id, ref_num_c, od_num_c, ALTIUS__Company__r.Name, Customer_Contact__r.Name,
(SELECT ALTIUS__Site__r.Name, ALTIUS__Site__r.ALTIUS__State__c,ALTIUS__Site__r.ALTIUS__Country__c FROM ALTIUS__Sites__r),
(SELECT ALTIUS__Product__r.ALTIUS__Product_Name__c,ALTIUS__Product__r.ALTIUS__Serial_Number__c  FROM ALTIUS__Products__r)
FROM ALTIUS__Contracts__c 
WHERE ALTIUS__Company__c IN :w.AccountId`

Comment: `SELECT ALTIUS__Product__r.ALTIUS__Product_Name__c,ALTIUS__Product__r.ALTIUS__Serial_Number__c  FROM ALTIUS__Products__c` this query runs fine.. gives the desired results

Comment: @sfdev first comment - updated the answer, second and consequent comments - I don't know the name of relationship of master-detail on `ALTIUS__Contracts__c` object, to get the right name, go to Setup -> Object Manager -> ALTIUS__Products__c (or ALTIUS__Sites__c) -> Fields & Relationships -> ALTIUS__Contract__c -> copy Child Relationship Name

Comment: This field defines a relationship between this object type and a "parent" object type. The Child Relationship Name is used in SOQL queries on the parent object type to refer to this object type. For example, Contact has a lookup field for Account. The Child Relationship Name for the lookup field on Contact is "Contacts" Therefore, you would use "Contacts" in Account queries to refer to Contact records whose Account field references a given Account. Accepting the default value is safe. If necessary, the name can be changed later.

Comment: Meaning that you should use in sub-queries for `ALTIUS__Contract__c` the names provided there and not `ALTIUS__Sites__r` and `ALTIUS__Products__r` respectively. I just assumed that those were the names, but apparently - no.

Comment: Thanks Mariia. Your Answer was very helpful in my scenario.